Heroku: promoting a staging app to production with multiple sevices
I have a services-based architecture in Heroku, with multiple apps defined in staging and production.  In my pipeline, the apps look like this:

In Stage:

app1-stage
app2-stage


In Prod:

app1
app2



When promoting a service to production from stage, the Heroku UI presents every app in production to promote a given service to.  However, if I'm promoting app1-stage to prod, the only application I want that promoted to would be app1.  It seems to be an extremely common and obvious use case, but heroku presents both app1 and app2 in the list to promote to, in their UI.  In fact, one of my team promoted one of my services to every production service accidentally, creating an outage.
Is there any way, either in the UI or via script / code, that I can create some kind of rule that would force any promotion of app1-stage to only be allowed to replace app1?  I haven't seen anything in the docs close to this, and I can't believe that everyone promoting a service to prod is constantly having to remove the other invalid options from the list manually.  It makes me think I'm doing something terribly wrong.
How do I constrain how apps are promoted?
